# DotNetOpenAuth 4.3 - Unexpected response Content-Type text/html

Tags: dotnetopenauth

Using the the OAuthAuthorizationServer and OAuthClient samples, I am getting the following:

```
[ProtocolException: Unexpected response Content-Type text/html]
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.VerifyProtocol(Boolean condition, String unformattedMessage, Object[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.Core\Messaging\ErrorUtilities.cs:205
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ErrorUtilities.ThrowProtocol(String unformattedMessage, Object[] args) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.Core\Messaging\ErrorUtilities.cs:238
   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ChannelElements.OAuth2ClientChannel.ReadFromResponseCore(IncomingWebResponse response) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client\OAuth2\ChannelElements\OAuth2ClientChannel.cs:101
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.RequestCore(IDirectedProtocolMessage request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.Core\Messaging\Channel.cs:750
   DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel.Request(IDirectedProtocolMessage requestMessage) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.Core\Messaging\Channel.cs:536
   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.ClientBase.UpdateAuthorizationWithResponse(IAuthorizationState authorizationState, EndUserAuthorizationSuccessAuthCodeResponse authorizationSuccess) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client\OAuth2\ClientBase.cs:341
   DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization(HttpRequestBase request) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1e6dbb6a394efdc4\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Client\OAuth2\WebServerClient.cs:164
   OAuthClient._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\SourceCode\Damikaa\DotNetAuthPoc\OAuthClient\Default.aspx.cs:37
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3064
```

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: Did you get solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

The reason could be from the urls you have given for your AuthorizationEndpoint and TokenEndpoint and the url that you create request to it for getting your response.

Make sure that you have set the proper urls for these items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a faulty authorization server. One that does not properly set the HTTP headers in its response.

Comment: Andrew what are the appropriate HTTP headers supposed to be? I have what I believe is correct. Please see this zip from Fiddler, https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3CtpOwTV8zKQ0hoRzgwUUl6M3c/edit?usp=sharing

You'll also notice FedAuth cookies. I replaced the forms authentication of the OAuth server with claims-based authentication, so that I can use that as my user for the User table in the OAuth server.

Comment: Responses from authorization servers to clients are expected to be encoded as a JSON object, and the HTTP header would therefore be: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Andrew. I'm currently on another project, but when I get back on this I will verify the HTTP headers being sent.